# Exception criteria exceeded : CPU time in SAS . How to resolve this error?

Tags: sas, runtime-error, teradata, cpu

I have a query regarding a piece of code that generates an automated report in Teradata.

```
PROC SQL;
&connect_db
execute (
CREATE TABLE table1 AS
(
 SELECT a.x1, a.x2, a.x3, b.y1
 FROM PreviousTable a LEFT JOIN DailyTable b
 ON a.acct_id = b.acct_id
 WHERE b.acct_ind =1 AND
 b.date <= a.date
) 
WITH DATA;
) by  db;
QUIT;
```

So in the above query throws  Exception criteria exceeded : CPU Time.
Could you help me understand how we change this CPU time error

Comment: 90% of the issues I had with Teradata were caused by trying to make tables that were skewed.  You do not appear to be telling Teradata what variable(s) should be use as the primary index. What type of variable is X1? How many distinct values does it have? What it is distribution.

Comment: Also want to point out that the above will effectively be an INNER JOIN due to the WHERE clause conditions, not a LEFT JOIN. If you really intend a LEFT JOIN then all these predicates belong in the ON clause.

Comment: Please tell us what macro variable "connect_db" is (`%put &connect_db;`), or better: put `option mprint;` in front of your code and share your log.